# g++ command not found in sh script

Tags: scripts, g++, sh

I don't know, maybe this is a duplicate, but I didn't find any help.

So, the problem. I have a simple problem - I made a script to automate C++ compiling a bit. Well, there's the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
PATH="/media/joris/LinuxStuff/C plus plus prog"
echo Path is $PATH
echo Name of file?
read filename
echo $PATH/$filename/$filename.cpp
echo Compiled file name?
read compfilename
g++ -o $PATH/$filename/$filename.cpp /media/joris/LinuxStuff/C\ plus\ plus\ prog/$filename/$filename
```

And this is what I get:

```
Path is /media/joris/LinuxDomenai/C plus plus prog
Name of file?
nope
/media/joris/LinuxStuff/C plus plus prog/nope/nope.cpp
Compiled file name?
yes
./comp.sh: line 16: g++: command not found
```

Please help?

Edit: if I compile in terminal, it works and which g++ gives me /user/bin/g++

Comment: Check your installation with `which g++`. What is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not overwrite `$PATH`. Use another name for this.

In your special case, the following should work:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -o "$PATH/$filename/$filename.cpp /media/joris/LinuxStuff/C plus plus prog/$filename/$filename"
```

Comment: Almost it. Problem: g++: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory

Comment: This is another problem. Open a new question.